# Include Multiple CSS in Redux Framework

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a new wordpress theme in which i used redux framework for creating the theme's options page.I passed my style.css path in function compiler_action()

```
function compiler_action($options, $css, $changed_values) {
            global $wp_filesystem;

            $filename = get_template_directory().'/style.css';


            if( empty( $wp_filesystem ) ) {
                require_once( ABSPATH .'/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
                WP_Filesystem();
            }

            if( $wp_filesystem ) {
                $wp_filesystem->put_contents(
                    $filename,
                    $css,
                    FS_CHMOD_FILE // predefined mode settings for WP files
                );
            }
        }
```

it worked but in my wordpress theme there is number of css include in my theme directory css folder how i include that folder also so that all css update dynamially.Please help me if you have any idea about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean so all your CSS update dynamically? Each CSS file has to be recompiled.

If you mean browser caching, then what you'll want to do is the "time" argument to the WordPress register/enqueue style, you pass in: filemtime(FILEPATH) as the time, and anytime the CSS is updated, it will change.